# Where can I ask questions about web-service like this?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Consider my question(s) is:

- I am looking for web-service that provides online data compression for web-browsing. In other words provides web surfing through data compression. Any such exist for use?
- [<s>Can I use Google data compression proxy on other browser like Firefox?</s>](https://superuser.com/q/945924/)
- How can I minimize data usage regarding web-surfing (note: Not recommendation for web-browser)

Thus, Where can I ask questions like above?

<sup>Note: Am I right when using word "web-services"?</sup>

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a proxy that compresses the data before sending to the web browser.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Can [software-recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) help?

Comment: Recommendation questions are expressly off-topic at [webapps.se]. This isn't about a web application anyway.

Comment: Regarding "web-services" -> [What is a “web service” in plain English?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226108/what-is-a-web-service-in-plain-english)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a web-service but a web-proxy because that is what can sit between your browser and a website and can be provided by third-parties, for example ISP's.

As your question will be a recommendation question you'll have a hard-time to find a site that accepts that because [the Q/A format doesn't fit on shopping questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Your best changes are your own ISP or a google search. Maybe in chat on superuser.com someone is prepared to help you. I doubt you can ask on [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) because you are looking for an external service, not for software that runs on your own device.

Comment: Thanks for replying helpfully. btw, I didn't understand (exactly) how this relevant with *shopping*.

Comment: You could also call it a list question: List your favourite/best (color|footballclub|president|car|artist|Tavern regular). There is not a single definitive answer.

Comment: Every recommendation is considered 'you are shopping for something', which is the type of questions we try to avoid.